# Как отправить тег <form> без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
    <div class="conteinar" id="modalcont">
        <div class="head">
            <p class="text-h">
                NAS
            </p>
            <div class="btn-grid">
                
                <button type="submit" onclick="Modaleshow()">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <p class="text-p">
                Модель NAS:
            </p>
            <input class="text-field" placeholder="Введіть модель NAS" type="text">
            <p class="text-p">
                Модель процесора:
            </p>
            <input class="text-field" placeholder="Введіть модель процесора" type="text">
            <p class="text-p">
                Оперативна пам'ять:
            </p>
            <input class="text-field" placeholder="Введіть оперативну пам'ять" type="text">
            <p class="text-p">
                Роз'єми LAN:
            </p>
            <input class="text-field" placeholder="Введіть кількість роз'ємів" type="text">
            <p class="text-p">
                Слоти для дисків:
            </p>
            <select class="select-t">
                <option class="text-field" value="1">1</option>
                <option class="text-field" value="2">2</option>
                <option class="text-field" value="3">3</option>
                <option class="text-field" value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <div class="photo">
                <img src="#">
            </div>
            <p class="text-p" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                Виберіть файл зображення:
            </p>
            <input class="file" type="file" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png">
            <input type="button" value="Підтвердити" class="buttonedit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
function Modaleclose() {
    document.getElementsById('modalcont').style.display='none';
}
function Modaleshow() {
    document.getElementById('modalcont').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('greybg').style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: Перехватить событие submit и в его обработчике сделать всё что вы хотите